# Next closest date and time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Inside of my `Auctions` table, I have a column called `Auction_StartDate`. The value of a row is like this: `2012-10-27 13:45:30`.

I need a query that will **return the next closest date and time** after that.  So if the next Auction_StartDate is `2012-10-27 18:30:00`, it should return that before the date turns to `2012-10-28`.

Comment: Do you just need the next closest date? Or do you need the id of the row with the next closest date? Also, are you saying you only want results on the same calendar day? Or if the next closest was "2012-10-28 05:00:00" would that be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I need it with the time.

Comment: That's not quite what I asked. Do you need the id of the row with the next closest date? Also does the next closest date have to be on the same calendar day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this one helps

```
    SELECT DATE(Auction_StartDate) closestDate
    FROM    Auctions
    WHERE   DATE(Auction_StartDate) > '2012-10-27'
    order by Auction_StartDate ASC
    limit 1
```

Comment: you need to add `ORDER BY closestDate ASC`, this will happen [click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/933ae/1)

Comment: @JohnWoo: We need closes date and DESC will never give us closest, I think it must be ASC :)

Comment: I need the time included in the result.

Comment: @Alec: replace "SELECT DATE(Auction_StartDate) closestDate" to "SELECT Auction_StartDate closestDate", will give you full column value

Comment: @Alec This doesn't actually answer your question. This won't return 2012-10-27 18:30:00 as per the example in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MIN` to find the closest value without using `LIMIT and ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT  MIN(DATE(Auction_StartDate)) closestDate
FROM    Auctions
WHERE   DATE(Auction_StartDate) > '2012-10-27'
```

## [SQLfiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8435/1)

Comment: Instead of MIN function we can use the LIMIT to optimize the query

Comment: thanks for correcting John, I checked in your fiddle and now saw that you already arranged in the ASC order, so in your case it works perfectly :)

Comment: -1 This won't work in the example provided by the OP. If the next closest date is on the same calendar day this won't return that value.

Comment: @Alec, Just remove `DATE`, do this `MIN(Auction_StartDate) closestDate`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to do this for every row, try this:

```
SELECT a1.id,
    (SELECT MIN(a2.Auction_StartDate) 
     FROM Auctions a2 
     WHERE a2.Auction_StartDate > a1.Auction_StartDate) AS nextStartDate
FROM Auctions a1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT (case when Hour(StartDate)>=12 then DATE_ADD(StartDate,
                  INTERVAL 1 DAY) else StartDate end) as 'date' FROM table  
    ------------------------------
    pleaes add your column name where is static date : 
    est on : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8435/19

    SELECT (case when Hour(StartDate )>=12 then 
       DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD(StartDate ,INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')                
       else DATE_FORMAT(StartDate , '%Y-%m-%d') end) as 'date'  from tabel
```