# the next closest date time from another column

Tags: mysql, date, time, subquery

I have a table with bookings. Basically appartment id, arrivaldate, arrivaltime, departuredate, departuretime.
I need to know the next arrival compared to each departure.
Based on posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832999/next-closest-date-and-time-in-mysql)  I 've got:

```
SELECT 
departuredate,
departuretime, 
    (SELECT 
        MIN(TIMESTAMP(arrivaldate,arrivaltime)) 
       FROM booking 
       AS next_booking 
       WHERE next_booking.arrivaldate > booking.departuredate
    ) AS n_a 
 FROM booking
```

This works fine as long as departure and next closest arrival are **not on the same day** and only a few hours apart.

Of course! I am comparing the dates in the WHERE statement.

But how do I compare both arrival date and time combined with departure date and time combined in the subquery's WHERE statement?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TIMESTAMP()` to combine the date and time when comparing.

```
SELECT 
departuredate,
departuretime, 
    (SELECT 
        MIN(TIMESTAMP(arrivaldate,arrivaltime)) 
       FROM booking 
       AS next_booking 
       WHERE TIMESTAMP(next_booking.arrivaldate, next_booking.arrivaltime) > TIMESTAMP(booking.departuredate, booking.departuretime)
    ) AS n_a 
 FROM booking
```

Things would be easier if you didn't split the times into separate date and time columns.

Comment: This works, thx. I separated the columns because I frequently need to update either date or time separatly which is quite a hassle in DATETIME format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700355/update-only-time-from-my-datetime-field-in-sql or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326548/update-only-time-in-a-mysql-datetime-field. So thats why.